# Why this SDL2 graphics code does not work as expected in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, ubuntu-18.04, sdl-2

The following code produce a colored window in Ubuntu 18.04 having **gdm3** desktop environment. But the same code does not produce a colored window in Kubuntu 18.04 having **KDE** desktop environment; instead the window seems kind of transparent and only shows the window frames. And when the window is dragged somewhere it freezes the whole UI as long as the window is not destroyed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Window * window = NULL;
SDL_Surface * surface = NULL;

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);   
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                                "Title of window",
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, //horizontal position of window
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, //vertical position of window
                                640, //width of window
                                480, //height of window
                                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN //flags
                                );
    if(window == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Window couldnt be created.\n");
    else
    {
        surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        if(surface == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Could not get window surface\n");
        else {
            SDL_FillRect(
                            surface,
                            NULL,
                            SDL_MapRGB(
                                        surface->format,
                                        0x00,
                                        0xff,
                                        0xff
                                        )
                            );
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_Delay(10000);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anything change if you add a proper event-loop instead of blocking for 10 seconds?

Comment: no change is there.

Comment: @PrakashBhattarai can we see resulting code? Your update loop needs both event flush and redraw. Draw&delay is not a valid way to display image.

Comment: @keltar should we redraw even if there is no update in surfaces?

Comment: @PrakashBhattarai yes because window manager is not responsible for keeping your image. If something happened to parts of your visible window (minimised, resized, overshadowed by other window, ...), window manager says you that event and you need to redraw. You've drawn before window manager was ready to get your image to screen, so if you check for events, you'll see WINDOW_EXPOSED event or something like that. You can redraw unconditionally for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to redraw the window in event loop after SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED event occurs; as mentioned in [libsdl](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID). The final code looks like this.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Window * window = NULL;
SDL_Surface * surface = NULL;
SDL_Event event;

int main() {
    int show = 1;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);   
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                                "Title of window",
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, //horizontal position of window
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, //vertical position of window
                                640, //width of window
                                480, //height of window
                                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN //flags
                                );
    if(window == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Window couldnt be created.\n");
    else
    {
        surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        if(surface == NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Could not get window surface\n");
        else {
            SDL_FillRect(
                            surface,
                            NULL,
                            SDL_MapRGB(
                                        surface->format,
                                        0x00,
                                        0xff,
                                        0xff
                                        )
                            );
            while(show) {
                while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                    if(event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
                        switch(event.window.event) {
                            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED:
                                printf("SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED event occured\n");
                                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
                                break;
                            default:
                                printf("other events\n");
                        }
                    } else if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                        show = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```